# Preserve axis ticks for nan values

Tags: pgfplots

I am reading in values from a table and plotting them with TikZ (a reproduced minimal example is given below). When x = 0.50, y = `nan` and the corresponding tick on the x axis is dropped.

**How can I preserve this tick?**

[image: plot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    X  Y
    0.50 nan
    0.55 2
    0.60 3
    }\mydata

    \begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            xtick = {
                0.50, 0.55, 0.60
            },
        ]
        \addplot table{\mydata};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could gather the information directly from the table using the capabilities of the `pgfplotstable` package which comes as an extention of `pgfplots` data handling capabilities. And set the `xmin=...,xmax=...` based on the unfiltered table information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread{
    X  Y
    0.50 nan
    0.55 2
    0.60 3
    }\mydata
    % Retrieve first X value in table
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{X}\of{\mydata}
    % Set \truexmin as this value
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\truexmin}{\pgfplotsretval}
    % Retrieve number of rows in table
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mydata}
    % Store it as an integer named \numrows
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    % Retrieve last X value in table
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\numrows}{X}\of{\mydata}
    % Set \truexmax as this value
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\truexmax}{\pgfplotsretval}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
            xtick = {
                0.50, 0.55, 0.60
            },
            xmin = \truexmin,
            xmax = \truexmax,
            enlarge x limits=true,
        ]
        \addplot table{\mydata};

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted this answer, but later realized that I had simply forgotten to set `xmax` and `xmin`. This is quite embarrassing, but your answer solved my problem nonetheless (and taught me a thing or two about using the `pgfplotstable` package), so of course it will stay as the accepted answer.

Comment: @eirikvaa Seen this, way, it sure looks overkill... This way at least you do not have to ensure that your user defined `xmin=...,xmax=...` encompass the complete dataset, so it may be more relevant if you have more complex data. Glad that helps anyhow